# PowerShell 7.0.x Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure-function-app, powershell-7.0

I have a .NET Core 3.1 class Library which uses a nuget package called [RazorEngineCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngineCore/) which references [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp v3.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/3.7.0) which then references [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common v3.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common/3.7.0) when I use this in a .NET Core Exe or PowerShell 7.1 it works without a problem but when I use PowerShell 7.0.x I get the following error message:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext, String ilPath, String niPath, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFromResolveHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.InvokeResolveEvent(ResolveEventHandler eventHandler, RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name)   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.OnAssemblyResolve(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
```

I have enabled fusion logging and there is no output and the inner exception provides no reference to any missing dlls. The powershell code I am calling is this:

```
    Add-Type -Path "$($PSScriptRoot)\ComponentHealth.Rendering.dll"

    $ViewModel = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name     = 'Kevin'
    }

    $template = "Hello @Model.Name"

    try {
        $output = [ComponentHealth.Rendering.Rendering]::Render("Bob", $template, $ViewModel) 
    } catch {
        $ex = $_.Exception
        $base = $_.Exception.GetBaseException()
        Write-Host $ex
    }
    Write-Host $output
```

I can't work out why this works in a exe app or PowerShell 7.1.x but not PowerShell 7.0.x. Unfortunately, I cannot use a different version of PowerShell as this needs to be added to an Azure App Function which is pinned at PowerShell runtime 7.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue, if you are trying and import a dll which has a higher version than is shipped with PowerShell Core runtime you will get exceptions trying to load the dll. We fixed the issue by recompiling the [RazorEngineCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngineCore/) package with lower versions of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp than were shipped with PowerShell 7.0.3 and everything now works correctly.